# export gridview to excel file

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, excel, export

i have this code
it keeps giving me error

```
Protected Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    Dim response As HttpResponse = HttpContext.Current.Response()
    response.Clear()
    response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=XXXXXX.xls")
    response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
    Dim s As System.IO.StringWriter = New System.IO.StringWriter
    Dim htw As HtmlTextWriter = New HtmlTextWriter(s)
    GridView1.RenderControl(htw)
    response.Write(s.ToString)
    response.End()
End Sub
Public Overrides Sub VerifyRenderingInServerForm(ByVal control As System.Web.UI.Control)

End Sub
```

the error is after i click on export  :  RegisterForEventValidation can only be called during

```
Render();
```

and it highlight  this  script

```
 GridView1.RenderControl(htw)
```

any advices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable event validation on page level:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" EnableEventValidation="false"  ...
```

But i would suggest [creating a real excel file](http://epplus.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WebapplicationExample) and write that binary to the stream instead of a HTML table. [EppPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/releases/view/42439) is highly recommended, [easy to use](http://fourleafit.wikispaces.com/EPPlus) and supports LINQ. ([GPLv2](http://epplus.codeplex.com/license)).

Comment: So was it helpful? If so, consider to accept answer so that it gets closed.

Comment: could you help on this for same.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40629644/how-to-export-excel-without-enableeventvalidation-false-because-of-lock-issues

Answer (score 0):

**   Copy Paste the below coding and test your output   **  before that **Add Reference** to **Microsoft Excel 11.0 Object Library/Microsoft Excel 12.0 Object Library/Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library**

```
        String fileName ="GVtoExcel";

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass ExcelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass();

        ExcelApp.Application.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
        for (int i = 1; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
        {

            ExcelApp.Cells[1, i] = dataGridView1.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;

        }
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {

            for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
            {

                ExcelApp.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();

            }

        }
        ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs(fileName);

        ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Saved = true;

        ExcelApp.Quit();
       System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ExcelApp);
       ExcelApp = null;
```