# Problems exporting gridView to Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, gridview

I am trying to export a `GridView` to Excel.

I have tried to follow steps found here:

1. http://www.programming-free.com/2012/09/aspnet-export-grid-view-to-excel.html#.UhUREpK1F9o
2. [export gridview to excel file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8094573/export-gridview-to-excel-file)

And other similar sites.

My `GridView` does not have any special properties different from default
and my `SqlDataSource` uses `filterExpression` if that is important.

When I try the above mentioned solutions no exception occurs, but the excel
is not produced.

**UPDATE**

I forgot to mention that the `GridView` is inside a `asp:Content` control. I heard
this might matter.

My code-behind goes something like this ( I have tried multiple things ).

```
Response.Clear();
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=FileName.xls");
Response.Charset = String.Empty;
EnableViewState = false;
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();

System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
GridView3.RenderControl(htmlWrite);

Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());         
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

Comment: How are you trying to export it? Show at least the codebehind. Have you used the debugger to see what happens?

Comment: @ I have used the debugger and like I said, no exception occurs, everything runs smooth, except the page is not displayed.

Comment: But this method is called, isn't it? Also, i assume that you have implemented [`VerifyRenderingInServerForm`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343630/gridview-must-be-placed-inside-a-form-tag-with-runat-server-even-after-the-gri/6343859#6343859).

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes, it is called on a button click. The button also resides in the `asp:Content` but NOT in the `GridView`

Comment: So the button is in a GridView(where exactly?) which sits in a MasterPage's `Content`? Have you seen my question about `VerifyRenderingInServerForm`? You are not using ASP.NET-Ajax, are you?

Comment: I am using some Ajax. In what way does this matter ?

Comment: You have to use a `PostBackTrigger` for the button instead of an asynchronous postback if it's in an `UpdatePanel`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter So to make it clear. My button is NOT inside the `GridView`, but both the button and the `GridView` are inside the `Content` control that is rendered inside the `Master Page`.  And yes, I have implemented ( empty impl ) for `VerifyRenderingInServerForm`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35951/discussion-between-coredump-and-tim-schmelter)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a GridView on the code behind and select the data seperately and export that Gridview as follows. So You don't have to worry about the Gridview on the Page.

```
Dim GridView1 As New GridView

SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM TableName"
GridView1.DataSource = SqlDataSource1
GridView1.DataBind()

Response.Clear()
Response.Buffer = True
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
Response.Charset = ""
Me.EnableViewState = False
Dim oStringWriter As New System.IO.StringWriter
Dim oHtmlTextWriter As New System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(oStringWriter)

GridView1.RenderControl(oHtmlTextWriter)

Response.Write(oStringWriter.ToString())
Response.End()
```