# how to export excel without EnableEventValidation="false" because of lock issues in excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, export-to-excel

I have a code for exporting excel on button click:

```
protected void btn_Excel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try {
            empData1.ShowHeader = true;
            bindGrid();
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=doc_name.xls");
            Response.Charset = "";
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
                foreach (TableCell cell in empData1.HeaderRow.Cells)
                {
                    cell.ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#fafafa");
                    cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#ff5d51");
                }
                empData1.RenderControl(hw);
                string style = @"<style> .textmode { } </style>";
                Response.Write(style);
                Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
                Response.Flush();
                Response.End();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception exp)
        {
            string st = exp.Message;
        }
    }
```

I was getting error:

```
RegisterForEventValidation can only be called during Render();
```

and what i did is:

`enableEventValidation="false"` on the `page_name.aspx` page

The export to excel worked fine after this on windows 7.

The issue came on windows 8, when i downloaded the excel on a windows 8 system's browser, though the file did downloaded completely, but on opening the file, it showed up with a error message that the file is corrupted, and i suppose it is because of disabling event validation.

when i checked the properties of that file, then it was locked up due to security reasons. I unlocked it from there, and i could open up the file then.

so is there any way to tackle the error

```
RegisterForEventValidation can only be called during Render();
```

without `enableEventValidation="false"` or tell me if i am missing something.

Comment: Create a real excel sheet, for example with [`EppPlus`](http://epplus.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WebapplicationExample)

Comment: Use my method... fill your control with whatever data you want. then create a page on the fly and then make the page render it. dont call the control render as it throws the exception. I havent tested this way but I am 99.99% sure it will work!. I dont have time to test this out.